# Custom menu in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a menu of this type in android?

[image: is it possible to create amenu of this type in android.?]

Comment: Make your question more specific and clear....

Comment: Putting your question in the alt text for the picture isn't a great way to ask it, since most people won't notice it...

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. That is specifically the J2ME style, 2-key menu for featurephones.

You COULD create your own ActionBar-style View that would have 2 buttons and tapping the button would bring up a Dialog; you would then position the Dialog's window so it looks like that. However it would have to be manually done and quite frankly would be a pain to get to look pretty and would be so different from any of the Android user-interface standards that I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. You just have to develop it from scratch.
But I wouldn't recommend creating this menu, because it's not how most of the Android Apps look like and to create a good user experience it should fell like Android and not like an old Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make such a menu. To make a View that looks like this, you will have to create a new xml layout file. The text boxes can be EditText objects, the buttons can be Button objects, etc. [This site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) has an intro on how to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this type of menu. But I created a separate view as you have shown and in setContentview pass that view. See the following code. It will set the view when menu button is clicked.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        setContentView(view)
        return true;

    }
```

Donot forget to vote me if my response is useful for you

Thanks
Deepak